# How to save text content from textarea or div tag to google drive

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api

I want to save text from my textarea html element to google drive.I have searched google drive api etc.All i got is this code :

```
<div class="g-savetodrive"
data-src="//example.com/path/to/myfile.pdf"
data-filename="My Statement.pdf"
data-sitename="My Company Name">
</div>

</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
window.___gcfg = {
lang: 'en-US'};
</script>


<script src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js' async defer>
</script>
```

but as you can see in the above code it searches my physical directory and is looking for a file.

how can i change source to like Document.getElementById("mytextarea").value or something like this.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you ought to be using [Files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) which was previously [Files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) in Drive v2.

HTTP request

This method provides media upload functionality through two separate URIs. For more details, see the document on media upload.

Upload URI, for media upload requests:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files
```

Metadata URI, for metadata-only requests:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
```

Here's a snippet in written in JS from the docs using Files.insert.

```
function insertFile(fileData, callback) {
  const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
  const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
    var metadata = {
      'title': fileData.fileName,
      'mimeType': contentType
    };

    var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
    var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
        JSON.stringify(metadata) +
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        base64Data +
        close_delim;

    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
        'method': 'POST',
        'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
        },
        'body': multipartRequestBody});
    if (!callback) {
      callback = function(file) {
        console.log(file)
      };
    }
    request.execute(callback);
  }
}
```